# not able to install phalcon ubuntu 19.10 with php7

Tags: php, ubuntu, phalcon

I am trying to install `phalcon` on `ubuntu 19.10` where php version is `php7.3`, `php7.1` and `php7.0`.

When I try to install `php-phalcon`

> sudo apt-get install php7.0-phalcon
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>        Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package php7.0-phalcon
>
> E: Couldn't find any package> by glob 'php7.0-phalcon'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-phalcon'

Same with `php7.1` and `php7.3`

Is there any way to install.

I also tried with `apt-cache search` but same.

Answer (score 3):

You can get it from `~ondrej` PPA :
the phalcon package is listed as available under
https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75

It's not listed at 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/php/

so my guess it was never originally delivered with Ubuntu

optionally: try `apt install php-phalcon` instead of specific `php7.x-phalcon`

EDIT: since none of the repos have currently phalcon available in them for 19.10 for unknown reason (listed on website but not possible to find via apt)
the only reasonable solution is to download it from

https://packagecloud.io/app/phalcon/stable/search?q=php7.3&filter=all&filter=debs&dist=

and install with

```
dpkg -i php7.3-phalcon<YOURFILE>.deb
```

Comment: already installed `ondrej` and it's not working. `E: Unable to locate package php-phalcon`

Comment: found it with `apt search phalcon` and updated my answer ;)

Comment: `apt search phalcon
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done`

Comment: then it looks like you don't have sury PPA installed or you didn't do `apt update` after adding it. it clearly provides this package:
```
php-phalcon/bionic 3.4.4-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
  full-stack PHP framework delivered as a C-extension
```

Comment: OK please show me output o f `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (possibly into some pastebin or something)

Comment: you're right, this is completely broken for 19.10 at this moment. please see my edit

Comment: `dpkg-deb: error: 'php73_phalcon.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive php73_phalcon.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php73_phalcon.deb`

Comment: yes, simply search for that package using the link I posted and download it directly, I see the link I have used with curl is server from cloudfront. I have also removed it from the answer to not misguide other people later.